# How to specify `this` in Mongoose Schema methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've tried to fiddle a bit around with Schema methods in Mongoose. And I was wondering how I could call informations from the schema I'm using, kinda like using `this`.

My Schema looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BuildingSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    info: String,
    level: {                                //  The current level of the template, default value is 1
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    },
    ressource: {                            //  Ressouces
        level: [{
            gain: [{                        //  Gain per level
                amount: Number,
                ressource: {
                    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
                    ref: 'Ressource'
                }
            }],
            cost: [{                        //  Cost per level
                amount: Number,
                ressource: {
                    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
                    ref: 'Ressource'
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
    storage: {                              //  Storage
        capacity: [{                        //  Storage capacity changes per level
            inside: Number,
            outside: Number
        }],
        stored: {                           //  Stored
            inside: [{                      //  Ressources stored inside
                amount: Number,
                ressource: {
                    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
                    ref: 'Ressource'
                }
            }],
            outside: [{                     //  Ressources stored outside
                amount: Number,
                ressource: {
                    type: Schema.ObjectId, 
                    ref: 'Ressource'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
},
{
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

/**
 * Methods
 */
BuildingSchema.methods = {
    printThis: function() {
         console.log('Print in prompt : ', this);
    }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Building', BuildingSchema);
```

I call the method like this from my controller

```
console.log('Print in browser : ', building.printThis);
```

So far my `print in prompt` returns `undefined`

Comment: Actually the keyword `this` will never return `undefined`, seems like your instance method incorrectly set or you missed export model...

Comment: what kind of data printing out the `building` instance? try out like this: `console.log('Print in browser : ', (new Building).printThis());`

Comment: ah I just saw that my `console.log('Print in browser : ', building.printThis);`s string was "print in prompt" instead. Meaning I never get into the method. Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: I'm glad it helped you figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what printed out the `printThis` method:

```
> building = new Building()
{ _id: 554899217377c9b97c54bb36,
  storage: { stored: { outside: [], inside: [] }, capacity: [] },
  ressource: { level: [] },
  level: 1,
    id: '554899217377c9b97c54bb36' }
> building.printThis()
Print in prompt :  { _id: 554899217377c9b97c54bb36,
  storage: { stored: { outside: [], inside: [] }, capacity: [] },
  ressource: { level: [] },
  level: 1,
    id: '554899217377c9b97c54bb36' }
undefined
>
```